# RSpec shows 2 different instances of model after save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

In debt management app I test the behavior, when user borrow money (create `expense_debt`) and then return them (create `income_debt`), app updates `expense_debt.returned` to `true`.

My `debt_rspec.rb`:

```
require 'rspec'

describe Debt do

  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)

  let(:expense_debt) { FactoryGirl.build(:expense_debt, user: user) }
  let(:income_debt) { FactoryGirl.build(:income_debt, user: user) }

  subject { income_debt }

  it 'update expense_debt.returned' do
    expense_debt.save
    income_debt.save
    expect(expense_debt.returned).to be_true
  end

end
```

This test fails, but in development everything works ok.

Then I've found that `expense_debt` and `Debt.first` has different values of `returned`. And if I rewrite test to:

```
it 'update expense_debt.returned' do
  expense_debt.save
  income_debt.save
  expect(Debt.first.returned).to be_true
end
```

it passes.

I can't understand, why they are not the same.

```
# This is expense_debt
#<Debt id: 1, ..., returned: false, ...>

# And this is Debt.first
#<Debt id: 1, ..., returned: true, ...>
```

Can somebody explain this behavior of RSpec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be it is using the cache version. Try this

```
  expect(expense_debt.reload.debt_returned).to be_true
```

Comment: Yes, it works! So, it was cache. I've completely forgot about it.